# Load iframe source based on URL parameters

Tags: php, iframe

I can't manage to load an iframe src based on URL parameter. I get a 404 page.

- Here is the boarding.php page with the iframe + parameter :
  http://sg-cms.azurewebsites.net/opespe/travel2/boarding.php?id=summer-1
- Here is the page that should be loaded in the iframe :
  http://soundsgoood.com/playlist/summer-1
- Here is the boarding.php code :

`<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div id="header">
            <a href="index.html">Back</a>
        </div>

        <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://soundsgoood.com/playlist/" style="width:100%; height:1000px;"></iframe>

        <script>
        (function() {
            var frameBaseSRC = document.getElementById("myIframe").src;
            var frameQueryString = document.location.href.split("id=")[1];
            if (frameQueryString != undefined) {
                document.getElementById("myIframe").src = frameBaseSRC + "?id=" + frameQueryString;
            }
         })();
         </script>
    </body>
</html>`

What do i miss here ?

Comment: If `src` is `http://soundsgoood.com/playlist/`  `document.location.href.split("id=")[1]` is always `undefined`

Comment: Thanks PHPglue, I tried some stuff but (as a novice) I can't make sense of your advice. Should I change the base src ? The thing is the iframed page do not have "id" in its URL : http://soundsgoood.com/playlist/summer-1

Comment: Why not just make the HTML `<iframe id='myIframe' src='http://soundsgoood.com/playlist/summer-1'></iframe>`? It's not as if an Event is occurring. Do style with CSS. Also, if you're going to use jQuery, use it. I don't even see a reason to use JavaScript in this particular case. I also have no idea why this is a PHP question. Your page could be a `.php` file, but that just means that your Server interprets it before sending it to the Client as an HTML page that could contain JavaScript, or whatever. You should use external CSS and JavaScript, so it's cached into the Client's Browser memory.

Comment: Thanks. The idea was to have links to different playlists on a page A, and to iframe the selected playlist on a page B. But I can't manage to get it working..

Comment: Why not use an `onclick` Event to change the `src` of the `iframe`? You can put your Elements into an Array and loop over them using a closure. This may be beyond your understanding of JavaScript. I wouldn't use links, but CSS stylized `div`s myself.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.

Replaced

```
document.getElementById("myIframe").src = frameBaseSRC + "?id=" + frameQueryString;
```

by

```
document.getElementById("myIframe").src = frameBaseSRC + frameQueryString;
```

Cool !